# Undefined Javascript Error On Click

Tags: javascript

not sure why I'm getting this error when I attempt to click on the button.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mm5crd3b/

Thanks

```
$(document).ready(function(){

(function() {
    var itemTracker = {
        // init
        init: function() {
            this.bindEvents();
        },

        // cacheDom
        cacheDom: {
            inputAdd: $('#inputAdd'),
            submitAdd: $('#submitItem')
        },

        // item
        item: {
            text: this.inputAdd.value,
        },

        // Bind Events
        bindEvents: function() {
            this.submitAdd.on("click", addItem);
        },

        // Add item
        addItem: function() {
            console.log("test");
        }

        // Remove item

        // Edit Item

        // Complete Item

        // Uncomplete Item
    };

    itemTracker.init();

})();

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are accessing the property in a wrong way,

```
bindEvents: function() {
  this.cacheDom.submitAdd.on("click", addItem);
},
```

When seeing your code, I can tell `cacheDom` is an object which holds `submitAdd` as a property in it.

Additionally,

```
item: {
 text: this.inputAdd.value,
},
```

This part of the code wont work as expected. You can write it as a getter to solve your problem.

```
get itemText() {
 return this.cacheDom.inputAdd.value,
},
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply,

The reason I used 'this.inputAdd' rather than using 'cacheDom.inputAdd' was because in this video it seems he does that?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m-NYyst_tiY

Am I mis interpreting what he's doing?

Comment: @JoeConsterdine The thing that he is doing is quite different from what you are doing. Also his code doesn't matches yours.

Answer (score 1):

There are minor changes to your bindEvents method

```
 bindEvents: function() {
        this.cacheDom["submitAdd"].on("click", this.addItem);
      },
```

submitAdd is a key in the cacheDom object so you have access them using cacheDom rather than directly and addItem is part of the object instance so you have access them using this. If you change this the error will be disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

It is not related to your code. It is a bug in that version of `jQuery` / `Sizzle`. The bug is there before you click on the button.

Exception source is `Sizzle` trying to initialize against the default document.

But your code is also wrong :)
I guess you wanted to be like this (and here the handler for click works)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

(function() {
  var itemTracker = {
    // init
    init: function() {
      this.bindEvents();
    },

   // cacheDom
   cacheDom: {
      inputAdd: $('#inputAdd'),
      submitAdd: $('#submitItem')
    },

    // item
   item: {
      text: this.inputAdd.value,
    },

    // Bind Events
    bindEvents: function() {
      this.cacheDom.submitAdd.on("click", this.addItem);
    },

    // Add item
    addItem: function() {
      console.log("test");
    }

    // Remove item

    // Edit Item

    // Complete Item

    // Uncomplete Item
  };

  itemTracker.init();

})();

});
```